# Removing label from Gmail email after X days using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I created a Google Apps Script `Code.gs` as follows to remove the Gmail label from every thread that is older than `X` days and labeled `Y`.

```
function archiveYThreads() {
// Every thread, older than two days, and labeled "Unread Feeds".
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Unread Feeds" older_than:2d');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].removeLabel("Unread Feeds");
}
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread), the function `removeLabel` exists. Alternatively, I found some sources that use `deleteLabel`. However, with both I get the error that both functions do not exist, after having set a time-based trigger:

[image: Screenshot Function not found]

Can anybody please help me detecting why the function does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to supply an object of type GmailLabel as the argument to removeLabel() method. Try this snippet.

```
function archiveYThreads() {
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Unread Feeds");
 var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Unread Feeds" older_than:2d');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does work when supplying the `GmailLabel` object as an argument. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @orschiro Alternatively, you can get rid of the for loop by using the `GmailLabel.removeFromThreads(threads)` function once you have the threads array.  
In the code above simply replacing the for loop with `label.removeFromThreads(threads)` will work.  
It will work faster an reduces completely the possibility of your script timing out if you have a very large array of threads

Comment: @Chikitulfo Thanks for your suggestion. Maybe Amit Agarwal can update  his solution?